# Querying two columns with multiple conditions in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Given a Model with columns a and b, I want to get three records where a and b are `a: 0 b: 3`, `a: 1 b: 4`, and `a: 2 b: 5`.

The following way of retrieving records would result in issuing the query three times.

```rb
as = [0,1,2]
bs = [3,4,5]

Model.where(a: as[0], b: bs[0])
Model.where(a: as[1], b: bs[1])
Model.where(a: as[2], b: bs[2])
```

To make one query, I need to write the following.

```
Model.where(a: as[0], b: bs[0]).or(Model.where(a: as[1], b: bs[1])).or(Model.where(a: as[2], b: bs[2]))
```

In the above example, the number of records to be retrieved was fixed to `3`. Is there any way to retrieve a group of records in a single query execution when the number of records to be retrieved is arbitrary `N` (the number of elements in as and bs is `N`)?

The way I can think of is to generate a query with a string, but I would like to achieve this with rails built-in functionality as much as possible.

Comment: "The way I can think of is to generate a query with a string", you can dynamically generate any type of argument passed to `where` but it all reduces to generating it on your end. Using a string is the easiest way as it doesn't depend on you calling `or` whenever you add a new condition. Active Record works well for some queries, but it won't fit all the cases, so I wouldn't mind using raw SQL for this one.

Comment: will this helps you? =>

a = :a 

b = :b

(as.size).times do |x|
 h = {}
 h[a] = as[x]
 h[b] = bs[x]
 puts h
end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fold the criteria list into an AR query using `#reduce`, something like

```
criteria_list = [
  {a: 1, b: 2},
  {a: 2, b: 3},
  {a: 3, b: 4},
]

criteria_list.reduce(Model.none) do |scope, criteria|
  scope.or(Model.where(**criteria))
end
```

(just but be careful - the resulted query might be very inefficient, depending on the criteria set)

Comment: Thank you! It allowed us to achieve what we wanted to do. I have also looked at the logs of the actual queries generated, and they appear to be efficient, with no N+1 problems, etc.

Comment: Could you tell me what possible patterns of inefficient queries you are concerned about?

Comment: @gnk `or` queries themselves have somewhat "bad" reputation in terms of performance and even smart modern planners can produce a suboptimal execution plan for a query with many `OR`s (especially when you conjunct very different criteria etc). If your criteria are sane and reasonable (and covered by the appropriately designed indexes) you will probably never encounter any performance issues here, but if you build a dynamic query based on the "unbounded" user input (like "arbitrary combination of arbitrary criteria is allowed") chances to get a very slow query grow